# How can I extract gene names for a metabolic pathway from KEGG?

Tags: python, pathway

*Note: this question has also been asked on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/274321/)*

I need the get the list of gene names involved in glycolysis (to put an example). Not manually, I need to do this in a script. Ideally with Python. I think KEGG is the proper database to do this, but any other (free) suggestion would do.

How can I do it?

Comment: To your knowledge there are other metabolic pathways, including metaCyc, reactome,...

Comment: I could see that this question is reposted on Biostars. Here is the solution, [https://www.biostars.org/p/274321/#274326](https://www.biostars.org/p/274321/#274326)

Comment: How to do vice verse, if i want to find all pathways associated with a list of genes using R or python? Please advise

Answer (score 6):

I whipped this little script up using the [KEGG API](http://www.kegg.jp/kegg/rest/):

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import urllib.request
import re
import sys
pathway = 'hsa00010' # glycolysis
url = "http://rest.kegg.jp/get/" + pathway
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
    lines = f.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
    want = 0
    for line in lines:
        fields = line.split()
        ## The list of genes starts here
        if fields[0] == 'GENE':
            want = 1
            ## The line with GENE is different
            print(fields[2].rstrip(';'))
        ## We reached the next section of the file
        elif want == 1 and re.match('^\S', line):
            sys.exit();
        ## We're still in the list of genes
        if want == 1 and len(fields)>1:
            print(fields[1].rstrip(';'))
```

Answer (score 6):

using the REST API of [togows](http://togows.dbcls.jp/): one can fetch a json structure of the genes associated to a kegg pathway. eg: http://togows.org/entry/kegg-pathway/hsa00010/genes.json

```
[
  {
    "3101": "HK3; hexokinase 3 [KO:K00844] [EC:2.7.1.1]",
    "3098": "HK1; hexokinase 1 [KO:K00844] [EC:2.7.1.1]",
    "3099": "HK2; hexokinase 2 [KO:K00844] [EC:2.7.1.1]",
    "80201": "HKDC1; hexokinase domain containing 1 [KO:K00844] [EC:2.7.1.1]",
    "2645": "GCK; glucokinase [KO:K12407] [EC:2.7.1.2]",
    "2821": "GPI; glucose-6-phosphate isomerase [KO:K01810] [EC:5.3.1.9]",
    "5213": "PFKM; phosphofructokinase, muscle [KO:K00850] [EC:2.7.1.11]",
    "5214": "PFKP; phosphofructokinase, platelet [KO:K00850] [EC:2.7.1.11]",
    "5211": "PFKL; phosphofructokinase, liver type [KO:K00850] [EC:2.7.1.11]",
    "2203": "FBP1; fructose-bisphosphatase 1 [KO:K03841] [EC:3.1.3.11]",
    "8789": "FBP2; fructose-bisphosphatase 2 [KO:K03841] [EC:3.1.3.11]",
    "230": "ALDOC; aldolase, fructose-bisphosphate C [KO:K01623] [EC:4.1.2.13]",
    "226": "ALDOA; aldolase, fructose-bisphosphate A [KO:K01623] [EC:4.1.2.13]",
    "229": "ALDOB; aldolase, fructose-bisphosphate B [KO:K01623] [EC:4.1.2.13]",
    "7167": "TPI1; triosephosphate isomerase 1 [KO:K01803] [EC:5.3.1.1]",
    "2597": "GAPDH; glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase [KO:K00134] [EC:1.2.1.12]",
    "26330": "GAPDHS; glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase, spermatogenic [KO:K10705] [EC:1.2.1.12]",
    "5232": "PGK2; phosphoglycerate kinase 2 [KO:K00927] [EC:2.7.2.3]",
    "5230": "PGK1; phosphoglycerate kinase 1 [KO:K00927] [EC:2.7.2.3]",
    "5223": "PGAM1; phosphoglycerate mutase 1 [KO:K01834] [EC:5.4.2.11]",
    "5224": "PGAM2; phosphoglycerate mutase 2 [KO:K01834] [EC:5.4.2.11]",
    "441531": "PGAM4; phosphoglycerate mutase family member 4 [KO:K01834] [EC:5.4.2.11]",
    "2027": "ENO3; enolase 3 [KO:K01689] [EC:4.2.1.11]",
    "2026": "ENO2; enolase 2 [KO:K01689] [EC:4.2.1.11]",
    "2023": "ENO1; enolase 1 [KO:K01689] [EC:4.2.1.11]",
    "5315": "PKM; pyruvate kinase, muscle [KO:K00873] [EC:2.7.1.40]",
    "5313": "PKLR; pyruvate kinase, liver and RBC [KO:K12406] [EC:2.7.1.40]",
    "5161": "PDHA2; pyruvate dehydrogenase alpha 2 [KO:K00161] [EC:1.2.4.1]",
    "5160": "PDHA1; pyruvate dehydrogenase alpha 1 [KO:K00161] [EC:1.2.4.1]",
    "5162": "PDHB; pyruvate dehydrogenase (lipoamide) beta [KO:K00162] [EC:1.2.4.1]",
    "1737": "DLAT; dihydrolipoamide S-acetyltransferase [KO:K00627] [EC:2.3.1.12]",
    "1738": "DLD; dihydrolipoamide dehydrogenase [KO:K00382] [EC:1.8.1.4]",
    "160287": "LDHAL6A; lactate dehydrogenase A like 6A [KO:K00016] [EC:1.1.1.27]",
    "92483": "LDHAL6B; lactate dehydrogenase A like 6B [KO:K00016] [EC:1.1.1.27]",
    "3939": "LDHA; lactate dehydrogenase A [KO:K00016] [EC:1.1.1.27]",
    "3945": "LDHB; lactate dehydrogenase B [KO:K00016] [EC:1.1.1.27]",
    "3948": "LDHC; lactate dehydrogenase C [KO:K00016] [EC:1.1.1.27]",
    "124": "ADH1A; alcohol dehydrogenase 1A (class I), alpha polypeptide [KO:K13951] [EC:1.1.1.1]",
    "125": "ADH1B; alcohol dehydrogenase 1B (class I), beta polypeptide [KO:K13951] [EC:1.1.1.1]",
    "126": "ADH1C; alcohol dehydrogenase 1C (class I), gamma polypeptide [KO:K13951] [EC:1.1.1.1]",
    "131": "ADH7; alcohol dehydrogenase 7 (class IV), mu or sigma polypeptide [KO:K13951] [EC:1.1.1.1]",
    "127": "ADH4; alcohol dehydrogenase 4 (class II), pi polypeptide [KO:K13980] [EC:1.1.1.1]",
    "128": "ADH5; alcohol dehydrogenase 5 (class III), chi polypeptide [KO:K00121] [EC:1.1.1.1 1.1.1.284]",
    "130": "ADH6; alcohol dehydrogenase 6 (class V) [KO:K13952] [EC:1.1.1.1]",
    "10327": "AKR1A1; aldo-keto reductase family 1 member A1 [KO:K00002] [EC:1.1.1.2]",
    "217": "ALDH2; aldehyde dehydrogenase 2 family (mitochondrial) [KO:K00128] [EC:1.2.1.3]",
    "224": "ALDH3A2; aldehyde dehydrogenase 3 family member A2 [KO:K00128] [EC:1.2.1.3]",
    "219": "ALDH1B1; aldehyde dehydrogenase 1 family member B1 [KO:K00128] [EC:1.2.1.3]",
    "501": "ALDH7A1; aldehyde dehydrogenase 7 family member A1 [KO:K14085] [EC:1.2.1.3 1.2.1.8 1.2.1.31]",
    "223": "ALDH9A1; aldehyde dehydrogenase 9 family member A1 [KO:K00149] [EC:1.2.1.3 1.2.1.47]",
    "221": "ALDH3B1; aldehyde dehydrogenase 3 family member B1 [KO:K00129] [EC:1.2.1.5]",
    "222": "ALDH3B2; aldehyde dehydrogenase 3 family member B2 [KO:K00129] [EC:1.2.1.5]",
    "220": "ALDH1A3; aldehyde dehydrogenase 1 family member A3 [KO:K00129] [EC:1.2.1.5]",
    "218": "ALDH3A1; aldehyde dehydrogenase 3 family member A1 [KO:K00129] [EC:1.2.1.5]",
    "84532": "ACSS1; acyl-CoA synthetase short chain family member 1 [KO:K01895] [EC:6.2.1.1]",
    "55902": "ACSS2; acyl-CoA synthetase short chain family member 2 [KO:K01895] [EC:6.2.1.1]",
    "130589": "GALM; galactose mutarotase [KO:K01785] [EC:5.1.3.3]",
    "5236": "PGM1; phosphoglucomutase 1 [KO:K01835] [EC:5.4.2.2]",
    "55276": "PGM2; phosphoglucomutase 2 [KO:K15779] [EC:5.4.2.7 5.4.2.2]",
    "2538": "G6PC; glucose-6-phosphatase catalytic subunit [KO:K01084] [EC:3.1.3.9]",
    "57818": "G6PC2; glucose-6-phosphatase catalytic subunit 2 [KO:K01084] [EC:3.1.3.9]",
    "92579": "G6PC3; glucose-6-phosphatase catalytic subunit 3 [KO:K01084] [EC:3.1.3.9]",
    "83440": "ADPGK; ADP dependent glucokinase [KO:K08074] [EC:2.7.1.147]",
    "669": "BPGM; bisphosphoglycerate mutase [KO:K01837] [EC:5.4.2.11 5.4.2.4]",
    "9562": "MINPP1; multiple inositol-polyphosphate phosphatase 1 [KO:K03103] [EC:3.1.3.80 3.1.3.62]",
    "5105": "PCK1; phosphoenolpyruvate carboxykinase 1 [KO:K01596] [EC:4.1.1.32]",
    "5106": "PCK2; phosphoenolpyruvate carboxykinase 2, mitochondrial [KO:K01596] [EC:4.1.1.32]"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Answers from Biostars:

[GeneSCF](https://www.biostars.org/p/108669/) 'prepare_database' module will extract all the pathways with corresponding genes as simple table format in plain text file. Check 'Two step process' (sub-heading) from the provided link (First step will do your job).

---

You can use [KEGG REST API](http://www.kegg.jp/kegg/docs/keggapi.html) for extracting gene names from the pathway. [Python request library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) can be used to make the REST calls to KEGG REST API and query information. Please follow [this tutorial](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python) if you are a newbie to the Python programming and REST web services.